# How can I split PHP up and reuse parts of it?

Tags: php

I'm trying to split a line of PHP up, the reason being I don't actually always need some of the code and so that I can reuse parts of it.

The main reason I'm doing this is because the currency I get shows more digits for some currencies e.g. 1.2562 instead of 1.25, so I want to use the substr function only on certain GET's and be able to modify it for other GET's.

http://prntscr.com/6ttw8o

symbol is always required, substr isn't, $converter always required, end part of substr isn't however it can change, new currency is required.

```
$symbol[2] . substr(($converter->convert($defaultCurrency, $newCurrency) * 1),  0, 4) . " <b>" .$newCurrency. "</b>";
```

I've tried doing this with explode, however I'm not entirely sure how to do it as I have never really had to split anything up before so I'm a little puzzled on how to go about it.

Once the code has gone through the GET checking which is the current one set, I want it to grab the specified split up code pieces and then output it.

Comment: you could create a variable that equals part of the code, and just concatenate it against  other lines when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in a function like this:

```
function formatCurrency($symbol, $converter, $defaultCurrency, $newCurrency, $factor=1.0, $suffix="", $substrChars=0) {
    if($substrChars>0) {
        return $symbol . substr(($converter->convert($defaultCurrency, $newCurrency) * $factor),  0, $substrChars) . $suffix . " <b>" . $newCurrency. "</b>";
    } else {
        return $symbol . ($converter->convert($defaultCurrency, $newCurrency) * $factor) . $suffix . " <b>" . $newCurrency. "</b>";
    } 
}
```

If you call it without the `$substrChars` parameter, it will omit the `substr()` call, otherwise it will strip all but the first `$substrChars` characters:

```
if( $_GET['currency'] === "GBP" ){
    $newCurrency = $_GET['currency'];
    $string = formatCurrency($symbol[1], $converter, $defaultCurrency, $newCurrency, 2.0, ".00", 0);
} elseif( $_GET['currency'] === "USD" ){
    $newCurrency = $_GET['currency'];
    $string = formatCurrency($symbol[2], $converter, $defaultCurrency, $newCurrency, 1.0, "", 4);
}
```

This solution is very readable because you immediately see the difference between the two branches in the conditional statement.

Comment: Could you give me an example of this function being used? with  "0, 5", "0, 4" and without any substr?

Comment: @Exhibitioner: Example added. I don't know if `$converter` is your own code. If yes, you should consider putting that formatting code in there. That would improve your structure and decrease the number of parameters passed around. I also don't understand why you need an extra factor, e.g. `2` for `GBP`.

Comment: The reason I need the "2" is because after I've ran through all of the GET'S I am going to then  output prices on the page with that format and they vary in price so I want to be able to modify the * 2 to whatever the new price is for that specific product.

Comment: How could I achieve something like this too so I can modify the factor? http://prntscr.com/6u2s99